# How can I eagerly import a subset from a lazy loaded library in an NX workspace?

Tags: angular, ngrx, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I am having the following situation for my application. It is an NX workspace with an Angular application and several Angular libraries. E.g.

```
/apps
  /myapp
  /myapp-e2e
/libs
  /movies
  /books
```

The *movies* and *books* libraries both contain an NgRX (forFeature) store and the corresponding NgModules are loaded lazily via routing in the *myapp* router configuration. Now I have the situation that I would like to import only the NgRX actions from either of these libraries but the Module itself should remain lazily loaded. The nrwl linting throws that it is not allowed to import from lazy loaded modules

> nx-enforce-module-boundaries:  imports of lazy-loaded libraries are forbidden

But having an extra shared library just for the store actions seems to be over the roof and I don't want to pollute the *libs* folder too much. Is it possible to import only a subset of a library and keep the corresponding Angular library module be imported lazily?

Comment: Hello, Did you manage to achieve it?